# LayoutInflater parent

Tags: android, layout-inflater

when inflate with parent null:

```
LayoutInflater I = getLayoutInflater();
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Relative);
        View v = I.inflate(R.layout.text,null);

        relativeLayout.addView(v);
```

[the text have params android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" but when add manual to the relativeLayout the params dosent work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haqMW.png)

But when I use this code :

```
   LayoutInflater I = getLayoutInflater();
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Relative);
            View v = I.inflate(R.layout.text,relativeLayout);
```

the text params works

[text params work and hello word in center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeVhg.png)

why?

Comment: because you relative layout is the parent to the view v, so you have to add the second argument as `relativeLayout ` and not null.

Comment: because you relative layout is the parent to the view v, so you have to add the second argument as `relativeLayout ` and not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you noticed you get this lint warning when you pass null as the parent?

[image]

Or have you noticed that the Views in xml have some attributes that start with the prefix `layout_` and other don't?

The attributes that start with `layout_` are used by the parent ViewGroups of the Views to measure, layout and draw the views. So you should always pass a parent ViewGroup to inflate a layout.

If you pass null as the parent, the inflater has no idea what is the parent of the layout you are passing. It could be a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` or some other layout. So if you don't pass a proper parent layout, the `layout_` params are ignored.

Comment: and when I use addView(v);  I put the text inside the RelativeLayout
<RelativeLayout
..........
........

>

<TextView
center........
>
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

so what the problem both are inside RelativeLayout so that mean RelativeLayout is the parent in Both ways

Comment: Only while the view is inflated, the xml attributes are parsed and applied to the layout. It is not done while a view is added to a layout.

Comment: oh so when I put the parent not null the xml attributes are parsed and applied to the layout but when I use null and add manual addView();...

the text are added but without applying the xml attributes?

Comment: yes, without applying only the xml attributes that start with layout_ prefix.

Comment: ok, it's clear now all android: Layout_ will be applied only and what about the third boolean paramiter?

Comment: The third boolean 'attachToParent'. If you pass true, it automatically adds the layout to the parent. Other wise it won't. Then you can add the layout to parent manually as: parent.addView( inflatedLayout ). So, passing true is the same as passing false and calling parent.addView()

Comment: You might wonder why there is this 'false' option. In case of RecyclerView, we have to inflate the layout in the onCreateViewHolder, but we won't add the layout to the parent there. Have you noticed we have to pass false inside onCreateViewHolder? There, the RecyclerView decides when to add and remove the view from the parent. But, if you write a custom view, inheriting any ViewGroup, there you can pass true to the attachToRoot param, as we have to add the inflated layout to the parent ViewGroup.

Comment: Another place where we have to pass false for attachToRoot is onCreateView of Fragment. There, the FragmentManager will handle adding/ removing the View from the parent ViewGroup. More info here: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/

Answer (score 1):

Params that begin with "android:layout_" are supplied to describe how a view should be placed in relation to it's superview, which you aren't supplying when you use the inflator to build the view.

This should be pretty obvious, but just use the second method you posted.